# Which object in Numpy Python is good for matrix manipulation? numpy.array or numpy.matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

It seesms like we can have n dimensional array by numpy.array
also numpy.matrix is exact matrix I want.

which one is generally used?

Answer (score 1):

Objects of type `numpy.array` are n-dimensional, meaning they *can* represent 2-dimensional matrices, as well as 3D, 4D, 5D, etc.

The `numpy.matrix`, however, is designed specifically for the purpose of 2-dimensional matrices. As part of this specialisation, some of the operators are modified, for example `*` refers to matrix multiplication.

Use whichever is most sensible for your work, but make sure you remain consistent. If you'll occasionally have to deal with higher-dimensional data then it makes sense to use `numpy.array` all the time (you can still do matrix multiplication with 2D `numpy.array`, but you have to use a method as opposed to the `*` operator).